# How to embed cordova webview into windows phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova, cordovawebview

I need to use cordova in my existing project which consists of native xaml files. My project is written on windows phone 8.1 platform. I found a cordova open source project written for windows phone 8.0. I retarget to WP 8.1, add it on my project and use cordovaview via adding reference to xmlns in mainpage xaml but after all it fails to build.

Secondly I also found there is a way we can create a cordova project on wp 8.1 which comes with Visual Studio as a development template. As I see it's all written on Javascript and I couldn't see any way to add native xaml page into the project.

So my question is "Is there any way to embed Cordova WebView into existing Windows Phone 8.1 Project?"

Thanks.

Comment: does this helps http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/wp8/webview.html?

Comment: this documentation is for windows phone 8.0 and doesn't support wp 8.1

Comment: but WP8 apps work on WP8.1, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedded Cordova is not really supported for WP8.1 as of today

Comment: The question is about Cordova's Embadded WebView and not about Embadded Cordova!